# Accessing FTP folder in c#

Tags: c#, .net, api

I want to access/ read text file from a ftp site but i encountered an error say's

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' to type
>   'System.Net.FtpWebRequest'.

Here's my Code in c#

```
string username = "username";
string password = "password";

FtpWebRequest tmpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri("http://crmweb.com.ph/ftp/ftpuser1/User/tbl_users.csv"));
tmpReq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Comment: Your URI is a http site, not an ftp, so use HttpWebRequest!

Comment: Your uri has "http" scheme, not "ftp". So WebRequest.CreateDefault factory method creates HttpWebRequest instead of FtpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible errors in your code:

1. You are using the wrong type, but the right URI
2. You are using the right type, but the wrong URI

**1.:**
If the address and protocol (http) are correct you have to use `HttpWebRequest`:

```
var tmpReq = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://crmweb.com.ph/ftp/ftpuser1/User/tbl_users.csv"));
```

**2.:**
If you want to open an FTP connection, you have to specify a valid ftp-address (use ftp://)

```
var ftpReq =  FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://bulk.resource.org"))
```